# VBA - WinHttpRequest.Send Progress

Tags: vba, winhttprequest

In my code I have the following line

```
Dim Http2 As New WinHttpRequest
Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False
Http2.Send
```

when the third line is executed, excel goes black and seems like it's not responding.
Is there a way to get a status on the operation? Could I make a progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer but it does not work. There is no Content-Lenght header. here is the result of GetAllResponseHeaders

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 16:30:23 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 12 May 2020 16:30:23 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=Sa-cFWD2CHr2DjK0+KE6GH4r; Path=/pvp; Secure;HttpOnly;Secure
Set-Cookie: ROUTEIDPVP=.14; path=/pvp; HTTPOnly; Secure
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

also I had to write the code as Class Module

Comment: That's unfortunate.  All the sites I tried had this header.

Comment: the transfer is in chuncks, is there a way to ask the server "how many?"

Comment: I did a quick search, and the answer appears to be "no".  I suppose an option would be to pop up an animated graphic in the Start event and remove the graphic in the Finish event.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the `http2` variable `WithEvents` then you can do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents Http2 As WinHttpRequest
Private URL2 As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Set Http2 = New WinHttpRequest
   Http2.Open "GET", URL2, False
   Http2.Send
End Sub

Private Sub Http2_OnResponseStart(ByVal Status As Long, ByVal ContentType As String)
   ProgressBar1.Value = 0
   ProgressBar1.Max = CSng(Http2.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length"))
End Sub

Private Sub Http2_OnResponseDataAvailable(Data() As Byte)
   ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + UBound(Data)
End Sub
```

If the "Content-Length" header isn't available, one option would be to play some sort of animation:

```
Private Sub Http2_OnResponseStart(ByVal Status As Long, ByVal ContentType As String)
   Animation1.Visible = True
   Animation1.Open "filecopy.avi"
   Animation1.Play
End Sub

Private Sub Http2_OnResponseFinished()
   Animation1.Stop
   Animation1.Close
   Animation1.Visible = False
End Sub
```